# Hibernate: Find only those rows that aren't in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

OK, I have mapped with annotations two tables with a bidirectional @ManyToMany relationship.

Now I want to return only the elements which aren't in a many to many relationship, and I'm trying to use the code from [here](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-write-many-to-many-search-queries-in-mysql-and-hibernate/), but It throws an exception at runtime.
Here's the HQL:

```
String hql = "select a from Article a " +
                "left join a.tags t " +
                "group by a " +
                "having count(t)=0";
```

Is there a better way to return those elements? Or to fix the error in this query?

The exception it throws now is:

```
column "article0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL ...
```

Comment: Could you provide SQL that Hibernate generates when accessing DB? It seems it tries to get all fields for mapping, but only one of them is included in 'group by' condition.

Comment: @Donz, I'll try to extract it, and meanwhile try the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is correct, but on some databases `group by a` is not enough, you have to enumarate all properties of `a`, such as `group by a.id, a.title`.

Alternatively, you can use the following query:

```
select a from Article a where a.tags is empty
```

**See also:**

- [16.12. The group by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping)

Comment: It works! but now I have >10 properties in my group by. Plus, if I change something in the model I have to change explicitly in the query. Can I do something like a.*? To select all the properties?

Comment: @moondowner: With `join` - no, but your task can be solved without `join`, see update.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would work, but you can give it a try:

```
String hql = "select a from Article a " +
                "where a.tags=null ";
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it returns: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`

Comment: Hmm! One way of debugging can be: Get the SQL generated by Hibernate, try to execute that query directly to your database through a standalone database client. See what error you get there. Try to fix the SQL query. When you have fixed, you will have better chances of figuring out problem with your HQL.